# Determining Authentication Provider

Tags: windows-authentication

Went to Central Admin > Security > Authentication Providers >

I see Zone==Default and Membership Provider Name = Windows
Integrated Windows authentication is checked and NTLM is selected

Is that claim based authenticity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's NTLM authentication.

Comment: Why this article makes it look like our current setup is claim based.  http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2011/02/sharepoint-security-authentication/

Comment: For me it looks like that's saying NTLM is classic mode, not claims.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of ambiguous words in the SharePoint auth landscape....

There are two Authentication Methods: Classic Mode and Claims Mode.

Classic Mode supports Windows NT authentication.
Claims Mode supports Windows NT, Forms-Based and SAML 1.1/WS-Fed authentication.

To see what is being used, you need to look at the "Edit Authentication" page in Central Administration. (Click on the Zone name). If in Classic mode, then there will be a section titled IIS Authenicatin Settings. If in Claims Mode, there will be a section titled Claims Authentication Types.